# how do i change color of a button and load a question if another button is pressed without loading the whole page?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am making an online exam website where users can log in give exams.
I have a panel beside the question where different question number button are given if you click on the buttons the question will appear from the database without loading the whole page.I am running into the problem of how do I do that?

THE HTML CODE-

```
**<div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info custom" style="margin-right:16px">13</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info custom" style="margin-right:16px">14</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info custom" style="margin-right:16px">15</button>
</div>**
```

How to write the jquery ajax and php code?

Comment: When you click each button execute ajax call which doesn't render the whole page.

Comment: how do i write the ajax call ?

Comment: @KaunishRoy check the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I have created php file (test.php) and the client side which executes the ajax call and gets the question according to question id.Code is below

PHP file code (test.php)

```
<?php 
//it's used because the server is local, without it throws console error
//and doesn't allow to proceed with the operation.
//No need for remote servers
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

if(isset($_GET['questionId'])){
    $qId = $_GET['questionId'];

    if($qId == 12){
      echo "Question 1";
    }

    if($qId == 13){
      echo "Question 2";
    }
}

?>
```

```js
$(".btn > button").click(function(){
    //get button text and send it to server file to give you back response accordingly
    var qId = $(this).text();
    alert("Question ID:"+qId);
    
    /*$.ajax({
       method:'get',
       url:'http://localhost/test.php'
       //send question ID to server file
       data:{questionId: qId }
    }).done(function( data ) {
       console.log( "Sample of data:"+data);
    }).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
       alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    });*/
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info custom" style="margin-right:16px">13</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info custom" style="margin-right:16px">14</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info custom" style="margin-right:16px">15</button>
</div>
```