# How to disable input field after submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I need help disabling an input field **after** the submit button is clicked. I'm currently using Laravel, so I'm not sure if the jQuery is placed somewhere else other than the view. I tried putting this jQuery code in  `index.blade.php,` but it didn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).onclick(function(){
         $("#pid :input").prop("disabled", true);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Select an asnwer if you are satisfied.

Comment: Resources -> view -> template , edit default.blade.php. Add `jquery.min.js` script in head tag

Comment: Let me clarify what I'm trying to do. I'd like to permanently disable an SSN field after submit. Meaning, once the submit button is clicked and the form submitted, that field can no longer be edited.

Comment: You are not satisfied with the answers?

Comment: @MariosNikolaou unfortunately no. My apologies for not making myself clear in the initial question. Your code worked, but it didn't permanently disable the field and the form didn't submit. There are multiple fields in the form, not just the one I want to disable.

Comment: In my answer when you submit the form, the input field is disabled.

Comment: @MariosNikolaou In your code, the only thing that changes is the field being grayed out after submit button clicked. The form doesn't update in database. When page is refreshed, the field can be edited again. :\

Comment: Do you use ajax?

Comment: @MariosNikolaou If it solves the issue, why not. I'm not familiar with it. If you have code please post and I'll try it.

Comment: Yes, ajax is asynchronous it doesn't render the whole page.It will only save the data in db and the input fields will stay disable.

Comment: @MariosNikolaou can you provide an example?

Comment: check the updated answer.

Comment: You insert data using AJAX?

Answer (score 2):

Just listen for a submit click, then set the Boolean `disabled` attribute of the input:

```
$("#submit").on("click", function() {
    $("#pid").attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

Comment: In this case, i think he should use the submit method.

Comment: As was mentioned in the initial question, I'm using Laravel. The index.blade.php file is not executing javascript at all. I think I'm supposed to put the js somewhere else, but I don't know where.

Answer (score 1):

Check my code.I have created an example of a form and input element.

For more info about serialization check this [link](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

You will send using ajax the input elements values to file.php, then the `echo` from the file.php will send to ajax call the data and the data will be printed in console.

After that the input field will be disabled.

file.php

```
<?php 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

if(isset($_GET['nm'])){
    $name = $_GET['nm'];

    echo $name;
}

?>
```

```js
$("#frm1").submit(function(e){

     //make sure you have name value in each input element
     $.ajax({
        method:'get',
        url:'http://localhost/file.php',
        data:$(this).serialize()
     }).done(function( data ) {
         console.log(data);
     }).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
         alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
     });

     //after submit disable the input elememt
     $("#nm").prop("disabled", true);

     e.preventDefault();
     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="frm1" action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="nm" name="nm" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry I meant when I run code snippet here, there's a script error

Comment: @Emerg fixed.I was submitting the form.

Comment: When I run code snippet, it gives a request failed error. Also, I'm a complete novice to this. Can you tell what I need to put in "url" and "sample of data" parts? Isn't the method "post" not "get"?

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55550593/how-do-i-change-color-of-a-button-and-load-a-question-if-another-button-is-press#comment97803486_55550593)

Comment: Can't I do an "isset" directly into the input attibute to disable it if filled? If so, can you provide an example?

Comment: You can, when ajax is finished the input element will stay disabled.Did you checked it?

Comment: I did but I'm so confused. It's gibberish to me.

Comment: You should know about wamp,ajax,html form,jquery?

Comment: Not really. I'm just adjusting current code I paid for to have someone else to do.

Comment: You paid someone and he didn't do it?

Comment: He finished the majority of the code but I'm just fine tuning it. If he did it, I would've been charged more. I'm trying to find the least complicated way to do what I want.

Comment: I have added a simple example to understand how it works.Instead of localhost you will add the remote server url or ip.You can install wamp and test the example that i have posted.

Comment: Am I supposed to put something where it says "sample of data"?

Comment: It's just text, it will display the data that will come from php file.

Comment: Ugh!! I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I keep getting request failed: error

Comment: You must run the php file using local server. E.g wamp

Comment: Ok so I got the file.php in the right location. But when I click submit, nothing submits. But the field is disabled. How do I get the form to submit then disable the field?

Comment: @Emerg it's written on console.If you don't know how to check it replace `console.log(data)` to `alert(data)`.You will see pop up with the name that you entered in input field.